# API call for GA Acquisition Channels report?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there a Google Analytics API call for the Acquisition Channels report?  The report is specifically https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/report/acquisition-channels

I don't see it in this list https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=traffic_sources

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, you need to add the [`ga:channelGrouping`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=channel_grouping&jump=ga_channelgrouping) dimension to your API calls to split results per channel.

If you want to get data about the **Acquisition -> Multi-Channel Funnels** reports, you need to use a different API than the `core`: the [`mcf API`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/).